# Dropbox website navigation bar effect

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I would like to recreate this transition effect from navigation bar on https://www.dropbox.com/. (I think It looks different in English version. Just change language to any other, to see the one I mean)

The way text and logo change color when each section scrolls beneath.
Is it possible to do that with just CSS or vanilla JavaScript?

While researching, I found this - https://github.com/salsita/jq-clipthru, but as I said, I'm interested in pure JS, not jQuery or other libraries. And I also found this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pq8jtm5L/.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("section div").each(function() {
    $(this).css('margin-top', $(window).scrollTop() - $(this).parent().position().top)
  });
});
```

I understand how the second example works, but I don't think that's how it's done on the dropbox website. It doesn't look like it changes any inline styles in DOM, or any type of positioning on elements with js. I guess the only thing manipulated in JS by scrolling is that white "sign in" panel, receiving a class, when you scroll.

Also, I don't think it has anything to do with background-attachment property. The logo is two img tags with svg in src attributes, and all the links are just plain text.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need JS at all (the reason you don't see any DOM state change in developer tools).
**The effect is purely achieved using CSS `clip`**

```
clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
```

on an absolute, full-size navigation parent (with the same size as the wrapping page).

```css
/*QuickReset*/
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.page {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 80px; /* prevent page text go underneath nav */
}

.nav-clip { /* size as parent .page, but act as nav clipper */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto); /* the magic */
  pointer-events: none; /* Allow pointer events to pass-trough*/
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
}

/* COLORS */
.bg-1 {background: #fbb; color: #000;}
.bg-2 {background: #0bf; color: #fff;}
.bg-3 {background: #bfb; color: #000;}
```

```html
<section class="page bg-1">
  <div class="nav-clip">
    <nav class="nav bg-1">STACKOVERFLOW</nav>
  </div>
  <p>1 Lorem ipsum...</p>
</section>


<section class="page bg-2">
  <div class="nav-clip">
    <nav class="nav bg-2">STACKOVERFLOW</nav>
  </div>
  <p>2 Lorem ipsum...</p>
</section>


<section class="page bg-3">
  <div class="nav-clip">
    <nav class="nav bg-3">STACKOVERFLOW</nav>
  </div>
  <p>3 Lorem ipsum...</p>
</section>
```